# Read custom HTML tag in Android and create link

Tags: android, regex, hyperlink

I get text from server like this:

```
sample text [myurl]link|http://sample.com[/myurl] and [myurl]link2|http://sample2.com[/myurl].
```

I need to create links from these tags. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to use something like this:

```
String s = "sample text [myurl]link|http://sample.com[/myurl]";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\[([^\\]]+)\\]([^|]+)\\|(http.+?)\\[/\\1\\]", "<a href=\"$3\">$2</a>"));
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/BmmGCN)

**REGEX**:

- `\[` - A literal `[`
- `([^\]]+)` - 1 or more characters other than `]`
- `\]` - Literal `]`
- `([^|]+)` - 1 or more characters other than `|`
- `\|` - Literal `|`
- `(http.+?)` -  A substring starting with `http` and then any characters but a newlone up to...
- `\[/` - a literal `[/`
- `\1` - A backreference to the text captured by the first group (the BB tag name)
- `\]` - literal `]`.

Output:

```
sample text <a href="http://sample.com">link</a>
```

Comment: Glad to be of help, Юра, please also consider upvoting if the answer proved helpful.